# Solving second order ODE using odeint in Python

Tags: python, ode

I want to solve this equation:

y'' + A*y' - B*y = 0

where y, A and B are functions of the same variable "a"

I tried the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as pyplot
from scipy.integrate import odeint


x0 = 0.,0.1 # initial conditions 
oe = 0.0 # cosmological constant density parameter
om = 1. # matter density parameter
h = 2.3E-18 # Hubble constant
w = -1. 

a = np.linspace(0.1,1,10) # scale factor


def H(a): # Hubble rate equation 
    return h*np.sqrt((om/(a**3.))+(oe/(a**(3.*(1.+w)))))

def A(a): # differential equation term 
    return (-3./(2.*a))

def B(a): # differential equation term
    return (3.*om*(h**2.))/((2.*(a**5.))*(H(a)**2.))



def system(X,a): # differential equation system
    X0 = X[0]
    X1 = X[1]
    X2 = -A(a)*X1 + B(a)*X0

    return X1,X2



x = odeint(system,x0,a)



pyplot.semilogx(a,x, linestyle='-', c="k", linewidth="2")
```

It returns a plot that doesn't make sense. I should get just one plot, with the maximum value of "x" being 1 at a=1. But I get the following plot:

Plot that I get:

[image: Plot that I get]

And the expected result is like the continuous line of the following graph:

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: Well what *do* you get? Why not add a figure? Please read [ask]. Also, having H^2 there will not do good to numerical precision. I suggest rewriting your equations so that the quantities are on the order of magnitude of 1, if possible,

Comment: Just follow example step by step http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.odeint.html

Comment: The code works as it should, you should transfer the question to the physics forum to discuss what to change to make the model conform to your expectations.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to change sign before B(a)*X0 in the function system(X, a). It should be negative according to your initial equation.

Comment: My bad. The original equation is y'' + A*y' - B*y